# How to center text in a radio wrapped in a label?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, alignment, center

I have a short example of 2 custom radio buttons each wrapped in a label, so that the whole area of each is clickable ( not just the radio button ).

I would like to keep the custom square radio button up the top left and then center the text in the middle of the clickable area. But I can't separate the text from the custom radio button.

Appreciate any help...

```css
input {
  display: none;
}


/*
 * Then, style the label so it looks like however you want.
 * Here's a quick rundown of how I did it here:
 */


/*
 * Some basic positioning styles, and we give it the pointer cursor to show 
 * that it's clickable
 */

label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 48%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
}


/*
 * With how I decided to build this, the position: relative is super important.
 * We're going to position a pseudo element within this element(As it is the containing box)
 */

label span {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 22px;
}


/* 
 * Because we're using pseudo elements, a content property is required to make them appear.
 */

label span:before,
label span:after {
  content: '';
}


/*
 * We are using the :before peudo elemnt as the actual button,
 * then we'll position the :after over it. You could also use a background-image,
 * font-icon, or really anything if you want different styles.
 * For the specific style we're going for, this approach is simply the easiest, but
 * once you understand the concept you can really do it however you like.
 */

label span:before {
  border: 1px solid #222021;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: white;
}

label span:after {
  background: #222021;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 3px;
  transition: 300ms;
  opacity: 0;
}


/*
 * This is the most important part of this whole file, if you understand what's happening here
 * you can really make this in so many different ways.
 * 
 * We start by selecting the input inside of the label, with "label input". From there we use the 
 * ":checked" selector to *only* select the input when it is checked. We then use the immediate sibling 
 * selector(+) to select the span, and then it's pseudo element :after(What we are using to mark the button)
 * Because we already styled the :after, all we have to do is set the opacity to 1, making it fade in.
 */

label input:checked+span:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label style="background-color: #ddd;"><input name="radio" type="radio" /><span>EMAIL</span></label>
<label style="background-color: lightgray;"><input name="radio" type="radio" /><span>PHONE</span> </label>
```

Comment: so you want the "email" in the middle (both vertically and horizontally) of the grey square?

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First think to do in your case is to restructure your html to separate the `input`, the customized input and the label text. Then you can simply use `position: absolute` and `top: 50%` to your label text and that all:

```css
input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 48%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;  
}

label .radio {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 22px;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

label .radio:before,
label .radio:after {
  content: '';
}

label .radio:before {
  border: 1px solid #222021;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: white;
}

label .radio:after {
  background: #222021;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 3px;
  transition: 300ms;
  opacity: 0;

}

label input:checked+.radio:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label style="background-color: #ddd;">
  <input name="radio" type="radio" />
  <span class="radio"></span>
  <p>EMAIL</p>
  
</label> 
<label style="background-color: lightgray;">
  <input name="radio" type="radio" />
  <span class="radio"></span>
  <p>PHONE</p>
</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use `display: flex` to position everything in the center, and use `position: absolute` to put the radio button on the top left corner.

So something like this:

```css
label{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    ...
}
input[type="radio"]{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Especially johannchopin ( example is perfect )

Comment: @aubreybourke Thanks ! Can you please `upvote` **all** helpfull answers ? :)